# Launching a new gnome-terminal from a gnome-terminal and running a command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, gnome

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco). I use `ctrl+alt+t` to launch a terminal window. From that window, I would like to launch a separate window that runs a command, say ls. My thoughts are that I would type `gnome-terminal -- ls` and it would work, but it a new window is not launched.

That said, if I simply type in `gnome-terminal` and hit enter, a new window launches (but without running the command I would like to be run in a separate window.

The overall requirements are very strict, because what I what I am doing. (I am actually trying to launch this window via an ssh connection, running as root, in a root Desktop session)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If I type gnorme-terminal in a terminal session, a new terminal window opens. So I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the new gnome terminal to stay open indefinitely. If so, you can try something like:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'ls; exec bash'
```

The exec bash after the ls command ensures that the new terminal stays open, otherwise you can use the sleep command instead to have it close after a certain ammount of time:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'ls; sleep 30'
```